# Awk Field number of matched pattern

Tags: awk, expression

I was wondering if there's a built in command in awk to get the field number of the phrase that you just matched.

> Banana is yellow.
>
> awk {
>        /yellow/{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~/yellow/) print $i}'

Is there a way to avoid writing the loop?

Comment: in your case it will print more than once if yellow is in more than 1 field.

Comment: have you tried your command? it doesn't work for me and `$i` is printing the match field other than field number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input string is a oneline string you can set the record delimiter to the field delimiter. Doing so you can use `NR` to print the position:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=FS}/yellow/{print NR}' <<< 'banana is yellow'
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Your command doesn't work when I test it. Here's my version:

```
echo "banana is yellow" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~/yellow/) print i}'
```

The output is :

```
3
```

As far as I know, there's no such built-in feature, to improve your command, the pattern match `/yellow/` at the beginning is not necessary, and also `$i` will print the matching field other than the field number that you need.

Alternatively, you can use an `array` to store each field and its corresponding index number, and then print field by arr["yellow"]